# Get screen content in Android (not take a screenshot)

Tags: android, image

I'm looking for a way to get the contents of the screen in android but not for taking a screenshot.

A little background, I recently broke up with someone and want to create an app that will "censor" photos of her (ie: just pixelate them). I know how to write a training algo to be able to detect her, and I can write a service in Android that will just run in the background, but I've not yet come across a way to get the screen contents. My thought was to look at the screen and if she shows up in Instagram, texts, or any app, just pixelate that portion of the screen (or put a black square over it or whatever).

Unfortunately the android docs haven't helped me much, so does anyone have any experience doing so, or can you point me towards any thing that would help?

I'm not sure if this is a violation of any rules, so if it is, my humblest of apologies, I'm just stumped and feel free to mark this closed.

Comment: Block her and her friends, save yourself the hassle lol